# JFrame GUI - RemoveAll

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a menu, that whenever I click on one of the options, I want to clear the screen (to clear all my JLabels and text areas). I use the code

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
getContentPane().repaint();
add(comboBoxOptions);
```

to clear the screen. After that I try to add a combo box, which adds but it doesn't show up. I can click on the options but it's hidden somehow I guess. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> How could I fix this?

Use a `CardLayout`, see [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Swing's layout management API is lazy, it won't update the layout's automatically, it waits till you tell it to.  This is a good thing.

You need to use `revalidate` to force the container hierarchy to be relaid out and `repaint` to schedule a repaint of the view, for example

```
getContentPane().removeAll();
add(comboBoxOptions);
revalidate();
repaint();
```